# EMR notebook to query dynamodb table

Tags: jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

I am using EMR notebook to fetch data from S3 and do some operation on the data and push into different s3 bucket. Basically code is written using ipython notebook (jupyter).

I need to query DynamoDb table to get some additional data. So, I have to write code in EMR notebook to query ddb.
Didn't find any related wikis and I am not sure whether it can be done?

Can someone please help me if it can be done? Also, it would be great help if you share some wiki how to do this

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the error you are facing and which kernel do you use pyspark, python3 ?

Comment: could you also share the code used to query dynamodb

Answer (score 0):

To query DynamoDB using python, you will need the python package boto3. If you are using PySpark or Python3 Notebooks this package should be available.

This [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html) explains how to use boto3 to query DynamoDB.